# getting next or upcoming record in my sql

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a table like the table shown as Table 1 and I want to write a query in which I want to show next seq_no of current row which is one greater then current row.

## Table 1

```
 Name     Marks  seq_no
 Akhil     10      1
 Mark      20      2
 Kim       40      1
 JOHN      40      2
 MIKE      40      3
```

## output required

```
 Name    Marks  seq_no next_s_no
 Akhil    10        1      2
 Mark     20        2      -
 Kim      40        1      2
 JOHN     40        2      3
 MIKE     40        3      -
```

Comment: Why do Mark and MIKE have no `next_s_no` ?

Comment: I think he wants it grouped by `Marks`, is the 20 a typo? Should the row with Mark in it have 10 in the `Marks` column or is it correct the way it is? If it is correct, I do not see what the correlation is between `next_s_no` and the rest of the records, unless `next_s_no` continues until `seq_no` resets to 1.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't get why **next_s_no** is **NULL** for **Mark** and **Mike**.

This is what I feel you are looking for.

> select Name,Marks,seq_no,**seq_no+1 as next_s_no** from table Table1;

This query would give you following output.

```
Name    Marks  seq_no next_s_no
 Akhil    10        1      2
 Mark     20        2      3
 Kim      40        1      2
 JOHN     40        2      3
 MIKE     40        3      4
```